# How to Abort or Exit from Redshift Query with a conditional expression?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to abort/exit a query based on a conditional expression using CASE statement:

- If the table has 0 rows then the query should go happy path.
- If the table has > 0 rows then the query should abort/exit.

```
    drop table if exists #dups_tracker ;

    create table #dups_tracker
    (
      column1 varchar(10)
    );

    insert into #dups_tracker values ('John'),('Smith'),('Jack') ;

    with c1 as
    (select
         0 as denominator__v
        ,count(*) as dups_cnt__v
    from #dups_tracker
    )
    select
      case 
        when dups_cnt__v > 0 THEN 1/denominator__v
      else   
        1  
      end Ind__v
    from c1
    ;
```

Here is the Error Message :

> Amazon Invalid operation: division by zero; 1 statement failed.

Comment: The error is being caused by `0 as denominator__v`, and then attempting to divide by that value. Won't it _always_ return an error?

Comment: Thanks John for responding. The real issue here is, Redshift SQL is trying to resolve the case condition values first and then doing the tree traversing. Due to that the query is failing without even evaluating the CASE expression. My requirement is how to exit/abort the query if the count(*) > 0. I mean if there are any rows in the table then error out the query or abort it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of aborting an SQL query. It either compiles into a query or it doesn't. If it does compile, the query runs.

The closest option would be to write a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html), which can include `IF` logic. So, it could first query the contents of a table and, based on the result, decide whether it will perform another query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic I was able to write to abort a SQL in case of positive usecase,

```
/* Dummy Table to Abort Dups Check process if Positive */

--Dups Table
drop table if exists #dups;
create table #dups
(
  dups_col varchar(1)
);
insert into #dups values('A');

--Dummy Table
drop table if exists #dummy ;
create table #dummy
(
dups_check decimal(1,0)
)
;

--When Table is not empty and has Dups
insert into #dummy
select 
count(*) * 10
from #dups
;

/*
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Numeric data overflow (result precision)
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Numeric data overflow (result precision)
  code:      1058
  context:   64 bit overflow
  query:     3246717
  location:  numeric.hpp:158
  process:   padbmaster [pid=6716]
  -----------------------------------------------;
1 statement failed.
*/


--When Table is empty and doesn't have dups
truncate #dups ;

insert into #dummy
select 
count(*) * 10
from #dups
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists temp_table;
create temp table temp_table (field_1 bool);

insert into temp_table
    select  case
                when false -- or true
                then 1
                else 1 / 0
                end as field_1;
```

This should compile, and fail when the condition isn't met.

Not sure why it's different from your example, though...

**Edit: the above doesn't work querying against a table. Leaving it here for posterity.**

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't seem to work against an actual table.  I'll leave this up here as a cautionary tale.